# Convergence of a certain series where the ratio test fails

Tags: real-analysis

I have spent many hours on this problem without success : We need to determine the convergence or divergence of the infinite series 
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{(2n^2 - 3n+1) (\ln n + (\ln n)^2)}.$$
A simple application of the ratio test yields the inconclusive Limit=1 . Any help is much appreciated...

Comment: No the log terms are in the denominator

Comment: Yes , now it is correct ..thanks for the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For large $n$ we have
$$\ln n>1$$
and so
$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{(2n^2 - 3n+1)(\ln n + (\ln n)^2)}
  <\frac{\sqrt{2n}}{(n^2)(2)}=\frac{1/\sqrt2}{n^{3/2}}\ .$$
So the series converges by the comparison test.

Note that the logs in this problem are actually quite unimportant, probably your teacher just put them in to annoy you ;-)

Comment: Thanks david for the quick reply but please look at the new Edit ....the logs are in the bottom

Comment: Saw that and just fixed it, please refresh the page ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your serie has positive terms, you can use the equivalents : $\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{2n^2-3n+1} \sim \frac{1}{2}n^{-\frac{3}{2}}$ and $\log(n) + (\log(n))^2 \sim \log(n)^2$

and for n big enough, $\frac{1}{2}n^{-\frac{3}{2}}\log(n)^2 < \frac{1}{2}n^{-\frac{3}{2}+\epsilon} $ that is the general term of a convergent serie, so the serie $\sum \frac{1}{2}n^{-\frac{3}{2}}\log(n)^2$ is convergent, and your original serie is also convergent

Comment: Thanks for providing another point of view